# How to use AngularFire without storing credentials in the git repo

Tags: angular, git, firebase, continuous-integration, angularfire2

I'm starting a new project with Angular & AngularFire.

According to what I've done previously and the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md), I'm supposed to add the firebase credentials inside of `/src/environments/environment.ts`.

But this is a project that I want to make the source-code public. Is there a way to avoid to  include the firebase credentials inside the git repository?

(and how to serve it locally)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys?hl=en#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different) states, the keys in the Firebase configuration for your web app are unlike usual API keys:

> Usually, you need to fastidiously guard API keys (for example, by using a vault service or setting the keys as environment variables); however, API keys for Firebase services are ok to include in code or checked-in config files.

Therefore, it's okay to put that configuration under source control even if it's publicly available. However, in some cases you might want to enforce limits of the API key usage. Check [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys?hl=en#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different) for detailed information.

With the configuration in your source code, you can run your Angular app locally as usual by running `npm start`.